# Is it possible to display Google Maps or OpenLayers map on the click of location of job?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

Is it possible to display a Google Maps or [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/popup.html) map on the click of location of job?

[image]

When we see details of job that page can include map, if possible.

[image: Map]

Comment: I don't know... don't people looking for a job generally have at least a rough idea where the country is that they're looking at? Given that they usually need to be legal to work in that country?

Comment: They would like to see jobs near their home location. maybe a map would give them better look to find nearby places.

Comment: Maps may be a good tool to give them access to roads or transport feasibility of employer location.(By Bus or car)

Comment: Sure, but I would imagine that is typically done in a separate tab/window using Google Maps. (That said, linking the employer's location to a separate Google Maps or OSM page probably wouldn't hurt.)

Comment: Yes by clicking on it , it should  display in another Window or popup

Comment: You'd need something of better resolution than the city name to do anything interesting.

Comment: This is not currently in our roadmap.